# Selenium does not detect iframe [Python]

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe, automation

im trying to make a small program to login into this site automatically  (es1.kingdoms.com/).

But the issue is that the iframe in which the login "popup" is, isn't detected by selenium.

As far as I know I have to use the switch_to function of the webdriver in order to acces the email and password fields inside it (since they aren't being detected either).

This is my code at the moment:

```
usernameStr= "example@example.com"
passwordStr= "12345"

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

nextButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginButton"]/button')
nextButton.click()

iframe1 =  WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'easyXDM_default7709_provider'))) 

browser.switch_to.frame(iframe1)

username = WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login"]/div[1]/input')))
username.send_keys(usernameStr)
```

The line in which the error takes place is in the assignation of 'iframe1'. The 'WebDriverWait' times out before it detects the iframe. In the html the iframe looks like this.

```
<iframe name="easyXDM_default7709_provider" id="easyXDM_default7709_provider" class="mellon-iframe" src="https://mellon-t5.traviangames.com/easyXDM/proxy.html?timestamp=1494602441065&amp;urn=%2Fauthentication%2Flogin%2FapplicationDomain%2Fwww.kingdoms.com%2FapplicationPath%2F%252Fes%252F%2FapplicationInGame%2F0%2FapplicationId%2Ftravian-ks%2FapplicationCountryId%2Fes%2FapplicationInstanceId%2Fportal-es%2FapplicationLanguageId%2Fes_ES%2FapplicationCookieEnabled%2F1%3Fmsname%3Dmsid%26msid%3D4qdpjbd8bdb72n7s5jede9uqa1&amp;xdm_e=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kingdoms.com&amp;xdm_c=default7709&amp;xdm_p=1" frameborder="0" style="position: static; top: auto; left: auto; outline: none; padding: 0px; width: 320px; height: 355px;" allowtransparency="1"></iframe>
```

I'have also checked that this iframe isn't inside another iframe.
Can anyone help?

Comment: because there are 2 iframes (one inside another)

Comment: but it still isn't detecting the first one. Shouldn't it detect at least the first one?

Comment: because ID is varying in this frame, use some other locator to identify this frame

Comment: okay, searching by class name instead seems to find it. Thank you so much! You solved it!